# Did the USA government aided Spanish Dictator Franco?

Tags: united-states, spain, dictatorship

Is it historically admitted that the USA aided Spanish dictator [Franco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Franco) in exchange for military bases and logistic support?

I'm looking for historians and authors against or in favour of these thesis.

Comment: Now it fails the "Lacks basic research" test (i.e. you have to inform yourself some about the subject, the very minimum is reading the wikipedia article about USA-Spain relationships, and ask questions that such an info does not understand/seems contradictory/is lacking in detail).

Comment: No, the idea is avoiding questions that can be answered by just copying & pasting from Wikipedia. From where you get the previous info is not relevant, Wikipedia is just an accessible, very basic resource for people who want to get some knowledge about some historical aspect. Now, after you get at least that knowledge, If you have questions that need more detail, just explain what you know so you can get a more focused answer.

Comment: I'm not so sure about your fist affirmation. StackExange encourage this kind of posts to enhance searches. I'm also looking for other authors or credible sources apart from what is shown on wikipedia.

Comment: @PbxMan While that might be the case on other sites, on History.SE at least, we have a long standing policy of avoiding questions that can be directly answered by Wikipedia. So the fact that you your self posted an answer that's a copy paste of wiki does not really help your case here, sorry.

Comment: The question might benefit from rephrasing.  Are you asking whether the US had friendly relations with  Spain during the Franco years, or whether the US aided Franco in becoming/staying the head of state?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As said in  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spain%E2%80%93United_States_relations#The_United_States_and_Franco) **yes**.

> ...Spain was blocked from joining the United Nations, primarily by the large Communist element in France. By contrast the American officials 1946 "praised the favorable 'transformation' that was occurring in US-Spanish relations.  United States needed Spain as a strategically located ally in the Cold War against the Soviet Union after 1947"

Comment: Spain was not the only neutral or former Axis ally to be blocked from UN membership.  The [list of those who finally joined in December 1955](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlargement_of_the_United_Nations#1955) is eye-opening

Comment: How is this "aiding" Franco, rather than establishing/maintaining friendly relations with a country that had been more-or-less neutral during WWII?